# UITableView in Swift not recognizing UINavigationBar, padding is off and part of tableview is hidden

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller

- constraint set to 0 at top, sides, and bottom
- only happens when view enters screen

I think an image would explain better than words:

Thanks!!!

[image: issue i'm experiencing]

Comment: Remove the top constraint, then ctrl-drag from the tableView to `TopLayoutGuide` in the left pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by unchecking something along the lines of "auto adjust margins" in attributes inspector, and having the top constraint == 64

Answer (score 0):

For tableview in the size inspector y value should be 64. Because navigation bar takes 44 and status bar 20. After this update constraint accordingly.